# Algorithm to find neighboring subimages

Tags: java, algorithm

I have an image and I am extracting a subimage to feed to my neural network. I am attempting to calculate the average output of all the subimages in that same neighborhood.

So if I have an original image (m X n pixels) and I found a subimage at (sub_x, sub_y) with size (sub_width and sub_height), I also need to extract subimages with the same size (sub_width and sub_height) at (sub_x + m, sub_y + n) where m and n go from 1 - 3.

I already have a working solution:

```
for (int subX = (x-3); subX < (x+4); subX++)
    for (int subY = (y-3); subY < (y+4); subY++)
      if ( (subX > 0) && (subY > 0) )
        if ( ((subX + width) < img.getWidth()) && ((subY + height) < img.getHeight()) ){
            counter++;
            testingImage = img.getSubimage(subX, subY, width, height);      
        }
```

x,y, width, and height are all integers of the original subimage I found.

img is the original full sized BufferedImage.

I'm not too happy about the performance though. Is there a faster/smarter way to do this?

Comment: How much of the execution time is spent in `img.getSubimage`? If much, maybe you could replace it with your own, specialized function.

Comment: I haven't timed it to be honest. However, I don't believe the issue is with the getSubimage method. The performance was pretty good up until I added this code block. I increased the computation required significantly. This is just a small part of the application, but I have N elements that need to go through this code block. Previously I only got one subImage so it was fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one simple thing you can do: get rid of those conditions inside loops. Calculate your ranges first, just once and then run the loops without range checks.

```
int subXStart = max(x-3, 0);
int subYStart = max(y-3, 0);
int subXEnd = min(x+4, img.getWidth() - width);
int subYEnd = min(y+4, img.getHeight() - height);
for (int subX = subXStart; subX < subXEnd; subX++) {
    for (int subY = subYStart; subY < subYEnd; subY++) {
        counter++;
        testingImage = img.getSubimage(subX, subY, width, height);
        // run your neural net
    }
}
```

You can also try switching the order of loops. The order that matches the memory ordering should be considerably faster.

Comment: That is definitely a smarter way to handle the ugly if-statements I had. Thanks!
The performance didn't improve significantly, but I guess there's really no way around this computational cost.